# Yii :: showScriptName set to false in urlManager doesn't work in IIS

Tags: php, iis, yii

I have a yii2 project runs in IIS7.5, below is part of my web.php:

```
 $config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/app',
    'viewPath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/resources/views',
    'runtimePath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/storage/framework',
    'vendorPath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\http\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/database.php'),
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => true,
            'rules' => [
                'api.shop.index'=>'shop/index',
                ...
             ],
        ],
    ],
    'modules' => require(__DIR__ . '/module.php'),
    'params' => $params,
];
```

below is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="my rules" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"  appendQueryString="true"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I set showScriptName to true, and navigate this url:

```
http://example.com/api/gateway/public/index.php/api.shop.index
```

it works well, if I set showScriptName to false, and navigate this url:

```
http://example.com/api/gateway/public/index/api.shop.index
```

the sever throws error:**No input file specified.**

Answer (score 0):

> 'rules' => [
>                   'api.shop.index'=>'shop/index',
>                   ...
>                ],

you get this error because you set the shop/index. so iis not able to find the index file without extension.